# Get SharePoint User JSOM

Tags: 2013, user, app, client-object-model

I want to get a User via JSOM.

The User is not the current user. 
The object I want to get should be SP.User (not String or anything)
I want to get the User by asking for his login ("domain\username") and get back the SP.User object.

I found some solutions using the PeopleManager. But I'm not sure if this is the correct way. Because if I get the PreferredName, isn't this just a string?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SP.Web.siteUsers property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj245773.aspx) gets the collection of all users that belong to the site collection:

```
var value = SP.Web.get_siteUsers ()
```

### How to get User client Object by email

```
function getUser(userName,Success,Error)
{
   var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var web = context.get_web();
   var user = web.get_siteUsers().getByEmail(userName);


   context.load(user);
   context.executeQueryAsync(function(){
       Success(user);  
     },
     Error
   );
}




//Usage
getUser('username@tenant.onmicrosoft.com',function(user){
       console.log('User Id: ' + user.ID);
    },
    function(sender,args){
       console.log(args.get_message());
    }
);
```

Note: in order to retrieve User by LoginName replace the method `getByEmail` with `getByLoginName`:

```
var user = web.get_siteUsers().getByLoginName(userName);
```

Comment: Great, I'm glad it helped.

Comment: What was the format of `userName` when using `getByLoginName`? Was it something like i:0#.w|domain\john.smith? getByLoginName doesn't seem to work for me using i:0#.w|domain\john.smith, domain\john.smith or john.smith